# SSRS colour expression for upward downward trend line chart

Tags: reporting-services, report, linechart, trend

I need to make a line chart with the month on horizontal axis and a value on the vertical axis.

I need to colour the line's segments in green if the trend based on the previous month is growing, or in red if the trend is decreasing.
[image: Graph]

I can't find a way to compare the values grouped by month, and I prefer not to  perform this by adding another query from db.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the Chart Series (the line of the graph) and select `Series Properties...`, click `Fill` on the left then click the `fx` button to enter and expression for the fill. Let's say your field is called Sales. Use the following expression for the Fill:

```
=IIF(Fields!Sales.Value >= Previous(Fields!Sales.Value), "Green", "Red")
```

This worked on my simple test. You may need to aggregate within your query (group by month and sum) for this to work properly.